# UV map doesn't work correctly

Tags: uv, export, import, uv-image-editor

I recently made my UV in blender, after I finished it I exported my model as FBX. After I imported it in another program, but I don't no why.. it see just one part of my UV.

Here it's result from blender [image: LmUXHi3] and here's on other app [image]
If anyone of you guys knows why I have that problem and has any idea how can I solve it, please tell me, I really need to know how to fix it :(.

Comment: It might help if you upload blend file. Which "other" app are you using?